# Can I run a bathroom fan and a bathroom light off 14 amp twin and earth

Tags: electrical

Can I run a 14 watt bathroom extractor and the bathroom light both of 14 amp twin and earth

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What is "twin and earth"?

Comment: Just want to point out that Amps = Watts / Voltage, so if you have a 100W light on a 120V circuit, that uses (100 / 120 = ) 0.83A.  That will let you figure out similar questions in the future if you know the wattage.

Comment: @JACK British for /2+gnd Romex.

Answer (score 4):

Yes a fan is usually a very light load there is nothing wrong with them being on the same switch.

My jurisdiction requires the fan to run after the light is turned off (or motion ceases) for up to 15 minutes. But prior to this it was quite common to have them on the same switch.

Comment: Stay safe out there Ed+

Comment: I believe my area requires them to be on the same switch if there is no window that opens in the bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

14 amps multipy by 110 is 1540 watt. The Bathroom Fan has max 30 and the light max 20. You can burn another 1490 Watt.

So the answer is.... For sure